# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django.contrib.static'

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 141, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 75, in get_response
    response = self._middleware_chain(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 36, in inner
    response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 90, in response_for_exception
    response = handle_uncaught_exception(request, get_resolver(get_urlconf()), sys.exc_info())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 125, in handle_uncaught_exception
    return debug.technical_500_response(request, *exc_info)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django_extensions/management/technical_response.py", line 37, in null_technical_500_response
    six.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/six.py", line 693, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 94, in __call__
    response = response or self.get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 36, in inner
    response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 90, in response_for_exception
    response = handle_uncaught_exception(request, get_resolver(get_urlconf()), sys.exc_info())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 125, in handle_uncaught_exception
    return debug.technical_500_response(request, *exc_info)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django_extensions/management/technical_response.py", line 37, in null_technical_500_response
    six.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/six.py", line 693, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 94, in __call__
    response = response or self.get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 36, in inner
    response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 90, in response_for_exception
    response = handle_uncaught_exception(request, get_resolver(get_urlconf()), sys.exc_info())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 125, in handle_uncaught_exception
    return debug.technical_500_response(request, *exc_info)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django_extensions/management/technical_response.py", line 37, in null_technical_500_response
    six.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/six.py", line 693, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 94, in __call__
    response = response or self.get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 36, in inner
    response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 90, in response_for_exception
    response = handle_uncaught_exception(request, get_resolver(get_urlconf()), sys.exc_info())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 125, in handle_uncaught_exception
    return debug.technical_500_response(request, *exc_info)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django_extensions/management/technical_response.py", line 37, in null_technical_500_response
    six.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/six.py", line 693, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 94, in __call__
    response = response or self.get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 36, in inner
    response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 90, in response_for_exception
    response = handle_uncaught_exception(request, get_resolver(get_urlconf()), sys.exc_info())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 125, in handle_uncaught_exception
    return debug.technical_500_response(request, *exc_info)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django_extensions/management/technical_response.py", line 37, in null_technical_500_response
    six.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/six.py", line 693, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 94, in __call__
    response = response or self.get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 36, in inner
    response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 90, in response_for_exception
    response = handle_uncaught_exception(request, get_resolver(get_urlconf()), sys.exc_info())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 125, in handle_uncaught_exception
    return debug.technical_500_response(request, *exc_info)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django_extensions/management/technical_response.py", line 37, in null_technical_500_response
    six.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/six.py", line 693, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 94, in __call__
    response = response or self.get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 36, in inner
    response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 90, in response_for_exception
    response = handle_uncaught_exception(request, get_resolver(get_urlconf()), sys.exc_info())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 125, in handle_uncaught_exception
    return debug.technical_500_response(request, *exc_info)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django_extensions/management/technical_response.py", line 37, in null_technical_500_response
    six.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/six.py", line 693, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 94, in __call__
    response = response or self.get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 36, in inner
    response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 90, in response_for_exception
    response = handle_uncaught_exception(request, get_resolver(get_urlconf()), sys.exc_info())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 125, in handle_uncaught_exception
    return debug.technical_500_response(request, *exc_info)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django_extensions/management/technical_response.py", line 37, in null_technical_500_response
    six.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/six.py", line 693, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 94, in __call__
    response = response or self.get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 36, in inner
    response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 90, in response_for_exception
    response = handle_uncaught_exception(request, get_resolver(get_urlconf()), sys.exc_info())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 125, in handle_uncaught_exception
    return debug.technical_500_response(request, *exc_info)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django_extensions/management/technical_response.py", line 37, in null_technical_500_response
    six.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/six.py", line 693, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/debug_toolbar/middleware.py", line 92, in __call__
    panel.generate_stats(request, response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/debug_toolbar/panels/staticfiles.py", line 126, in generate_stats
    "staticfiles_apps": self.get_staticfiles_apps(),
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/debug_toolbar/panels/staticfiles.py", line 168, in get_staticfiles_apps
    for finder in finders.get_finders():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/finders.py", line 283, in get_finders
    yield get_finder(finder_path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/finders.py", line 292, in get_finder
    Finder = import_string(import_path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/module_loading.py", line 17, in import_string
    module = import_module(module_path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 941, in _find_and_load_unlocked

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django.contrib.static'
```

I have been trying to get to the root of this error without any luck, I believe it came up while I was doing some refactoring.

I will appreciate another set of eyes on this.

Comment: It should likely be `django.contrib.staticfiles`. Did you by any change changed that in your `settings.py`?

Comment: great let me check from there, I did some general refactoring on pycharm, maybe it changed that

Comment: Great, it's working now.

Comment: onto the next issue regarding my css files suddenly not showing in production.
thanks for the help!

Comment: @BernardBetaBerlinParah: they never do *by design*. Django's static files are not served in production, because it would be unefficient, and likely insecure. For more info, see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/#configuring-static-files

Comment: yea, I will be connecting it to an S3 bucket or use whitenoise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error complains about a module it can not find:

```
django.contrib.static
```

This is likely a string in the [**`INSTALLED_APPS`** setting [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#installed-apps). The name of the module is however:

```
django.contrib.staticfiles
```

You thus should alter the `INSTALLED_APPS`, and use that string, like:

```
# settings.py

# …

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # …
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    # …
]

# …
```

Comment: Had the same issue but could not find anything wrong with INSTALLED_APPS. Turns out I must have somehow replaced 'staticfiles' with 'static' in an installed package, don't ask me how. From there it was an easy fix, uninstalling all packages from the virtual environment via `pip freeze | xargs pip uninstall -y` and then reinstalling via `pip install -r requirements.txt`.

Answer (score 1):

Since this question showed up when i had a similar issue : I ran into an error message saying

> "**ModuleNotFoundError:** No module named 'django.contrib.staticusers'"

My issue was that I forgot to put a comma in my INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py

Writing :

```
"django.contrib.sessions",
"django.contrib.messages",
"django.contrib.staticfiles"
"users",
```

Instead of :

```
"django.contrib.sessions",
"django.contrib.messages",
"django.contrib.staticfiles",      <- comma here
"users",
```